# Axios GET Request: Params Not Passed to Express Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

In postman

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/article/659bd71fd17c285560041681
```

and i get:

```
id: 659bd71fd17c285560041681
type: String
```

in the app:

```
const getArticleByID = async function () {
    const articleId = '659bd71fd17c285560041681'
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/article/${articleId}`)
  }
```

and i get:

```
undefined
undefined
```

why?

the controller code:

```
exports.getArticleById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(typeof id);
    const article = await Article.findById(id);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'got it!',
      article
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

How is the request from postman any diffrent from the request from the app?

Comment: make use of browsers developer tool to inspect the network request.

Comment: hi, when i inspect that request, i have, and go to response, i have the data, but when i want to console.log it, i get undefined.